# Making a list of strings lowercase in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of strings  `["Hi", "hELLO", "nO"]`

and I want to convert everything to lowercase. I wrote a function for this:

```
import Data.Char(toLower)
makeSmall xs = map toLower xs
```

It compiles, but when I do `makeSmall ["Hi", "hELLO", "nO"]` it gives me this error

```
<interactive>:2:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: "Hi"
      In the first argument of ‘makeSmall’, namely
        ‘["Hi", "hELLO", "nO"]’
      In the expression: makeSmall ["Hi", "hELLO", "nO"]

<interactive>:2:17: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: "hELLO"
      In the first argument of ‘makeSmall’, namely
        ‘["Hi", "hELLO", "nO"]’
      In the expression: makeSmall ["Hi", "hELLO", "nO"]

<interactive>:2:25: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: "nO"
      In the first argument of ‘makeSmall’, namely
        ‘["Hi", "hELLO", "nO"]’
      In the expression: makeSmall ["Hi", "hELLO", "nO"]
```

I'm trying to understand how I can make my function work for a list of strings, instead of just a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`toLower :: Char -> Char`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:toLower) maps a `Char` to a `Char`, this means that `map toLower` will take a *single* `String`, and it will return a `String`.

If you want to handle a *list* of `String`s, you should use a second `map`:

```
makeSmall :: [String] -> [String]
makeSmall xs = map (map toLower) xs
```

or shorter:

```
makeSmall :: [String] -> [String]
makeSmall = map (map toLower)
```

We thus make a mapper that uses `map toLower` as map function. This function will thus work on a *single* `String`. Since we make thus a mapper for this, we work on a *list* of `String`s.